# How to use array as id in the backbone

Tags: backbone.js

In the backbone, I have a json structure from the web server like this.(Note, I will only receive a bunch of documents, so not for restful service)
**{ 'stations':[station1,station2], 'geo':[lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2 ....]}**, in which 'stations' array has only two numbers who represents the bus stations number, while 'geo' represents the intermediate geolocation points between the two stations. and usually in the application, I could get the stations array in whatever array[station1,station2] or [station2,station1], and then I use this stations array as a unique id to get the 'geo' array - the intermediate geo loation points.

For example, **{'stations':[38306,38304],'geo':[ 53.21579073715244,-2.8958864745734445,53.26019,-2.9422970000000532]}**,  meaning I have two stations numbered 38306 and 38304, and 4 length array 'geo' representing 2 geo points.

```
window.stanoxPoints = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        "stations":new Array(),
        "points":new Array()
    }           
});

window.stanoxPointsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: stanoxPoints,
  url:"http://localhost:8080/geo",
});

var stanoxCollection = new stanoxPointsCollection();
stanoxCollection.fetch({
        success:function(collection,response){
            console.log('fetch the data success');
            collection.each(function(data){
                console.log(data.get('stations')+"   "+data.get('points'));                             
            })
        },
        error:function(collection, response){
        }
    })
```

so I design the model simply in this way above, and fetch the data using the collection, but when I want to query the data, there is something wrong,

```
stanoxCollection.get([38201,38202])    //undefined
```

My question is if I only use the 'station' array to get the 'geo' array, how can I make it the 'station' as id or index in the backbone model, and no matter what the order of the array 'stations', e.x [station1,station2] or [station2,station1] it can get me the array of geo points, only when stations array order is reversed, the order of geo array is reversed too.

Now I have tried to idAttribute: 'stations', so since original id is [38201,38202], so 
 console.log('fetch get by id', stanoxCollection.get([38201,38202]).get('points'));// works
 console.log('fetch get by id', stanoxCollection.get([38202,38201])); // doesn't work for reversed array as id

is there way to deal with it?

Comment: Does the server return a json array or just a single json object like you show?  Does your `success` callback get hit? Does it log anything to console? Seems like maybe you are trying to fetch a collection when there is only a single object.

Comment: It is not a single object, the server will return a json array, fetch receives the success, and  console.log(data.get('stations')+"   "+data.get('points'));    works for me. so I am bit confused why collection doesn't work when I used collection.at(0).get('stations'), saying 'get' is undefined

Comment: I expect `stanoxCollection.get([38201,38202])` to not work, as `get` takes a model reference or model id. Are you doing `stanoxCollection.at(0).get('stations')` in or after the `success` callback? If not, then the error you see would be expected.

Comment: Yes, stanoxCollection.at(0).get('stations') works after the success callback, but what should I do to use use the 'station' array to get the 'geo' array, 'station' as the id ?   stanoxCollection.where({'stations': [38201,38202]});  doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you just add a new function that performs this special `get` logic you need as you seem to require that objects may have multiple keys. I'd also thought maybe the `id` could be converted to a string rather than stored as an array.

Comment: You can do what @WiredPrairie said, try using `collection.find(function(model){ return true if model is the one you want });`.  But I am wondering, how do you get the stations you need to find in the collection? Why are they sometimes in a different order?